# Using Azure Storage to Replace Win2008 File server?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We are looking to replace our normal Win2008 R2 File server with a Azure Cloud based solution.   Our Current use scenario is something like this:

Server A, Location A
Hosts 4gb of Data

Server B, Location B
Hosts 4gb of Data

Server A and B are Replicated.

Users access Data like:
  \Domain-Name\DFSShare\ShareName

Many have Mapped Drives to the DFS Shares.

Can I use the Azure Storage to Replace this?  I'd like to still have the users map Drives to the same shared storage areas on Azure.

I Would also need the same Security Permissions setup so all the users have the same permissions that they do for the Existing File Server storage. So I'd like Active Directly Integration.

Is this something that Azure Storage can do for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might I recommend a product like StorSimple? This will accomplish the type of functionality you're after without need for costly development.

Comment: That looks like I'm still having to maintain my Server A, Server B in this scenario. Its just using an iSCSI type array that is linked to the Cloud.   I want to get rid of Server A and not have to worry about maintaining it.   We have an Existing Hyper-V Environment with iSCSI Back end Drive arrays. It works fairly well, though ever time we need to shut down for Server updates and iSCSI Firmware updates we seem to be down for many more hours than we really need to be,   the iSCSI  Drive Array has 16 2TB Drives in it. Its Mostly full.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a virtual server in Azure Iaas with a VNET and have a site-to-site VPN to your office. For users not in the office, you can have a VPN solution or install WebDAV on the file server and map drives over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot direct-map local-server drive letters to cloud storage (which is triple-replicated), although individual Compute instances may do so. Also, mounting an NTFS volume inside a blob is a single-writer scenario, though multiple readers may snapshot and access these drives. All this to say no, this won't replace your network shares.

As @Brent pointed out, [StorSimple](http://www.storsimple.com/) is a good solution to explore, since it's an appliance that provides network share replication to blob storage transparently (and encrypts data prior to pushing it to Windows Azure). This would at least obviate the need for maintaining your replication server, as well as providing offsite replication.

Comment: Looking through the StorSimple website, its not clear if it can be used as a NAS type device and hads Windows Active Directory Integration for security.   Or if its regular NAS/iSCSI device with a Passthrough to cloud option too? or is it Local Storage that is backed up to the cloud or?

Comment: Way I understand it (and I'm not expert) is that is has a local cache but persists most data back to the cloud. From your local network pov, it looks just like any other local network file share. I'd recommend reaching out to the StorSimple folks and getting additional information. I haven't worked directly with them, but when I've talked to their folks at trade shows, they've always been friendly and open about their prouct.

Comment: Still Requires Servers to Connected to the StorSimple Array for server service. All the usable storage seems to be on the Array first and any 'old', backup, snapshot data is then pushed to the cloud automatically. Its pretty much like any other iSCSI Array, though has a cloud backend that it can replicate/backup/shapshot to.   The $25K starting cost for the unit is pretty steep compared to the $6K 16 Bay x 2TB Drives that we have. We wanted to relieve the dependance on Physical devices. Someone pointed this out:[link](http://gladinet.blogspot.com/2011/06/amazon-s3-as-network-drive.html)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a file system driver using the dokan library, which you can take a look at here:

https://github.com/richorama/AzureBlobDrive

I wouldn't say it was lightning fast, and it doesn't implement every feature of NTFS, but it might work for you.